# Node.js get response outside app.post

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I want get response, to save cookie.. I used express on node.js

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", ["dok=javascript"]);
})
```

I want to do outside of app.post - real time used socket.io

for example:

```
socket.on('Login-clicked', function(data) {
     if(data == ok) {
       res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", ["dok=javascript"]);
     }
});
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do here is access res in socket.on('Login-clicked') event.To do that first make res global.

```
global.res={};
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  global.res=res;
});


socket.on('Login-clicked', function(data) {
     if(data == ok) {
       global.res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", ["dok=javascript"]);
     }
});
```